# “pgfkeys package error ” when doing a molecule (texmaker, linux)

Tags: texmaker, chemfig, pgfkeys, linux

The following code works fine when I run it on overleaf or texmaker for windows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

    \chemfig[atom sep=2em]{*6(=-=-=-)}
    
\end{document}
```

When I use it on texmaker for linux (lubuntu 18.04) I have the next error:

> **! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/atom sep', to which you passed '2em', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you
> misspelled it. See the pgfkeys package documentation for
> explanation.**

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possibly you have an older TeX installation on Ubuntu.

Comment: I confirm: no error on Debian with pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020)

Comment: @Shredder For me it works fine. You can maybe try `\setchemfig{atom sep=2em}` before the `\chemfig` comand ...